# Allow alphanumeric and #, replace comma and separate on space

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to do the following in a regex:

```
1. allow alphanumeric characters
2. allow the # character, and comma ','
3. replace the comma ',' with a space
4. split on space


sentence = "cool, fun, house234"

>> [cool, fun, house234]
```

Comment: In your example, commas are used as split points, not replaced by a space. The question might not be accurately phrased. Also, you should double quote in your result like `"cool"` to make it clear that `cool` is not a local variable, nor that the whole bracketed thing is the resulting string.

Comment: What do you mean by 'allow `#` and `,`'? What is supposed to be done with characters that are neither alphanumeric, `#`, nor `,`? What do you mean by 'allow' if `,` is turned into a space end eventually used as a split delimiter, while `#` is not?

Comment: I want to split on space, some people might enter ',' thinking it is a splitter, so I want to remove those characters or replace with a space.

Comment: Then, what's wrong with my answer?

Comment: Why didn't you simply say 'split on a space or a comma (followed by space)? And, what about my second comment?

Comment: , is allowed, and gets converted to a space.  other characters are removed, sorry I assumed that is what a regex would do and that was clear.

Comment: your right I could have said split on a comma or space since when it splits it removes that character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple way to do it:

```
sentence.scan(/[a-z0-9#]+/i) #=> ["cool", "fun", "house234"]
```

Basically it's looking for character runs that contain `a` to `z` in upper and lower case, plus `0` to `9`, and `#`, and returning those. Because comma and space aren't matching they're ignored.

You don't show an example using `#` but I added it 'cuz you said so.

Answer (score 0):

You can do 1 and 2 with a regular expression, but not 3 and 4.

```
sentence = "cool, fun, house234"

sentence.gsub(',', ' ').split if sentence =~ /[0-9#,]/

=> [ "cool", "fun", "house234" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"cool, fun, house234".split(",")
 => ["cool", " fun", " house234"]
```

You can just pass the "," into the split method to split on the comma, no need to convert it to spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, what you wanted is this?

```
string.gsub(/[^\w, #]/, '').split(/ +,? +/)
```